# JSON into Django

Tags: django, json, django-models, django-forms

I'd like to take advantage of all the field validation that comes with ModelForm and the convenience of handling related objects that comes with inlineformset_factory however I'd like to be able to post JSON data instead of using forms on my site.

In the past I've been using hidden forms and then serializing the form data and sending that to the server for AJAX like communication.

I'd prefer to do this in a less hacky way - ie. somehow co-opt forms to accept JSON data in a nice way.

Any suggestions/ examples?

Comment: Do you want to generate the form dynamically, or do you have an existing form class? Form constructor's data argument assumes a dictionary- in other words, django.forms does not care if you are binding data from request.POST or json.loads().

Comment: @fest does the data that I bind from json.loads have to follow the naming conventions of the Form? Or can they just be objects with pk set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the data via:

```
import json
data_dict = json.loads(data_json)
```

and then creating a new instance of the factory via

```
YourFactory(**data_dict)
```

Comment: But will the Factory object be expecting the keyword args to match the ones it generates for the form? ie. will it expect things like "isVisible" with the value "on" because it's a checkbox?

Comment: I can't really tell you. What was the result of your tests?